# I need help figuring out why my regular expression doesn't seem deterministic

Tags: python, regex

I use a regular expression to extract chords from input text files. While it works most of the time it fails on a certain file.

This is my regexp code:

```
def getChordMatches(line):
    import re

    notes = "[ABCDEFG]";
    accidentals = "(?:#|##|b|bb)?";
    chords = "(?:maj|min|m|sus|aug|dim)?"
    additions = "[0-9]?"
    chordFormPattern = notes + accidentals + chords + additions
    fullPattern = chordFormPattern + "(?:/%s)?\s" % (notes + accidentals)
    matches = [removeWhitespaces(x) for x in re.findall(fullPattern, line)]
    positions = [x.start() for x in re.finditer(fullPattern, line)]

    return matches, positions
```

This is the result when it works:

```
    line:      Em             C  C/B
 matches: [u'Em', u'C', u'C/B']
position: [5, 20, 23]
```

This line is from a file that doesn't produce the correct result:

```
    line:   Am           Am/G       D7/F#                 Fmaj7
 matches: [u'Fmaj7']
position: [48]
```

Where should I start digging? Encoding, special characters, tabs, ... ?

*edit*

This is where above output is from:

```
line = unicode(l, encoding='utf-8') 
matches, positions = getChordMatches(line) 
print '    line:', line 
print ' matches:', matches 
print 'position:', positions
```

*edit*

The full regex pattern is:

```
[ABCDEFG](?:#|##|b|bb)?(?:maj|min|m|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]?(?:/[ABCDEFG](?:#|##|b|bb)?)?\s
```

*edit*

A hexdump of the failing line (I think):

```
hexdump -s 45 -n 99 input.txt 
000002d 20 41 6d 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 41 6d 2f 
000003d 47 20 c2 a0 20 20 20 20 20 20 44 37 2f 46 23 20 
000004d 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 
000005d 46 6d 61 6a 37 0a 49 20 6c 6f 6f 6b 20 61 74 20 
000006d 79 6f 75 20 61 6c 6c 20 73 65 65 20 74 68 65 20 
000007d 6c 6f 76 65 20 74 68 65 72 65 20 74 68 61 74 27 
000008d 73 20 73 
0000090
```

*edit*

As mentioned in the accepted answer it was caused by a non breaking space. Using `line = unicode(l, encoding='utf-8').replace(u"\u00A0", " ")` solves the problem.

Comment: I probably need to see the hex dump to figure out what caused the problem.

Comment: hexdump of what, the input files?

Comment: it seems to me that most of what you have there could all be consolidated on a single line. it would (i think) improve clarity when the regex is easily readable as one line.

Comment: `>>> print matches, positions`
`['Am ', 'Am/G ', 'D7/F# ', 'Fmaj7 '] [1, 14, 25, 47]`
Seems nothing wrong here, are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: Works for me with the example given, except that it requires a space at the end. I suspect pseudo-whitspace issues or something similar.

Comment: @bouke I'm printing the output from getChordMatches so I figure it has to be?

Like this:
`line = unicode(l, encoding='utf-8')
matches, positions = getChordMatches(line)
print '    line:', line
print ' matches:', matches
print 'position:', positions`

Comment: @MdaG: At least of the line that causes the problem.

Comment: @nhahtdh Using hexdump is new to me, but I think this gives characters 45 to 99 (line mentioned in the main post) in the input text file: `hexdump -s 45 -n 99 input.txt 000002d 20 41 6d 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 41 6d 2f
000003d 47 20 c2 a0 20 20 20 20 20 20 44 37 2f 46 23 20
000004d 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
000005d 46 6d 61 6a 37 0a 49 20 6c 6f 6f 6b 20 61 74 20
000006d 79 6f 75 20 61 6c 6c 20 73 65 65 20 74 68 65 20
000007d 6c 6f 76 65 20 74 68 65 72 65 20 74 68 61 74 27
000008d 73 20 73                                       
0000090`

How do you add newlines?

Comment: @MdaG: You should add it to your question. From what I see, there are some weird character, but it shouldn't make your regex fail to match.

Comment: Are you sure "deterministic" is the right word for the title? Is it giving different results on the same input?

Comment: @NotAUser You're right. I didn't put that much thought into the title. The same input always gives the same result.

Comment: `pattern = r"[ABCDEFG](?:#|##|b|bb)?(?:maj|min|m|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]?(?:/[ABCDEFG](?:#|##|b|bb)?)?\s"
line = "  Am           Am/G       D7/F#                 Fmaj7 "
re.findall(pattern, line)`
Works fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem has to do with the following two bytes:

000003d 47 20 **c2 a0** 20 20 ...

This seems to be a UTF-8 encoded non-breaking space (U+00A0). It wouldn't surprise me if this is what's tripping up your regex.

Comment: Thank you! I see I need to learn how to make use of hex dumps. How did you know c2 a0 was a non breaking space?

Comment: @MdaG: They jumped out because they were greater than `7f` in hex, which is the highest ASCII char. I conjectured that the encoding was UTF-8, and used http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder

Comment: I also notice this one, but don't know why it would mess up the whole thing, if the file is read as ASCII.

Comment: @nhahtdh it's encoded as UTF-8 before being used. i.e. `line = unicode(l, encoding='utf-8') ` I added it in an edit earlier today.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is you are giving a line with character that is not matched by \s after the chord while the regex expression requires a space character. In any case the regex expression is wrong because it requires a space after the last chord.

Try to use \b instead of \s

(Edited after comment)

Comment: Tabs are also matched by ``\s``